# What does a single "||" mean in pytorch-geometric documents?

Tags: graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

For example the "||" (\Vert) in https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#torch_geometric.nn.conv.GATConv

Comment: I think it means "concatenation" operation, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[That documentation page](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#torch_geometric.nn.conv.GATConv) includes a link to an [arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10903.pdf) that includes the following (bottom of page three)...

> [image]
> where [image] represents transposition and || is the concatenation operation.

So yes, || is the concatenation operator.